# Extract and replace with value from another table oracle

Tags: oracle, replace, extract

I have a value which is retrieved from a column. A typical value would be like below

1\1\1\1\4\1\99\ **610000102**\2\6\0\4\6\50\ **536870969**\2\0\4\1\99\ **610000103**\2\6\0\4\6\51\ **536870969**\2\4\7\SUSPEND\4\2\99\ **536871469**\2\2\0\

I need to replace the numbers highlighted in bold. The actual value for numbers would be held in another table. So for example the first bold number **610000102** needs to be queried from a different table say ***select value from table where number = '610000102'*** and the value has to be replaced like

1\1\1\1\4\1\99\ **value1** \2\6\0\4\6\50\ **value2**\2\0\4\1\99\ **value3**\2\6\0\4\6\51\ **value4**\2\4\7\SUSPEND\4\2\99\ **value5**\2\2\0\

***Below is the behaviour of bold numbers***

1. The number of digits in them is not fixed
2. The chars/numbers to the left of or right of bold numbers is not
   fixed
3. The number of bold numbers can be n and all needs to be replaced
   with its corresponding value from another table
4. The numbers will always be within **"\ \"**

Please help in suggesting a solution

Regards 
Naveen S

Answer (score 0):

First query:

```
with t as 
     (select '1\1\1\1\4\1\99\610000102\2\6\0\4\6\50\536870969\' str from dual)
 select regexp_substr(t.str, '[^\]+', 1, level) n
   from source_table t
connect by regexp_substr(t.str, '[^\]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

This query breaks string to numbers:

```
n
-
1
1
1
1
4
1
...
```

After that join this query with table, that contains substitution values. Let's say it has values only for numbers `610000102`, `536870969` and so on (only for numbers that have to be replaced). After joining gather numbers in one string with delimiter `\` (works in oracle 11.2 or higher):

```
with t as 
     (select '1\1\1\1\4\1\99\610000102\2\6\0\4\6\50\536870969\ ' str from dual)
select listagg(nvl(t2.value, nums.n), '\') within group (order by nums.l)
  from (select regexp_substr(t.str, '[^\]+', 1, level) n, level l
          from t
       connect by regexp_substr(t.str, '[^\]+', 1, level) is not null) nums
        left join table2 t2 on nums.n = t2.number;
```